# Windows 8.1 dont have hyper-v - cant use Windows Phone Emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone, windows-8.1, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

Lately i wanted to get into Windows Phone 8 development and i installed Visual Studio 2013 + Windows Phone SDK 8 + Visual Studio 2013 Latest update.
My system parameters are:
- 8gb ram
- Windows 8.1 64bit system
- Intel i5
The moment i try to run a Windows Phone project a dialog appears and it says:
Title - " Cant start the windows phone emulator"
Subtitle - "The Windows Phone Emulator requires Hyper-V.Your PC is missing the following pre-requisites required to run Hyper-V:
-Windows 8 Professional(64 bit)"

After i saw that i checked for how to upgrade Normal Windows 8.1 to Windows 8.1 Professional.
With no luck i tried to find out more about to install Hyper-V with the BIOS configuration with no luck as well.

Usually i develop on Android with Eclipse(with the Emulator) so i can't understand the reason why a emulator of Windows Phone can't run on my system.

P.S
I dont have Hyper-V feature in the Windows Feature list to Turn off/on
Thanks heads up for each answer! :)

Comment: If your problem is with Hyper-V, you may have better luck at http://superuser.com

Answer (score 2):

The error is saying you need Windows 8.1 x64 Pro or Enterprise to be able to install Hyper-V.  You can still develop phone apps in the edition of Windows 8.1 you have but you must debug on on a windows phone the emulator will not be available

Comment: First , Thank you Ken
But i knew that already the problem is that my system supports SLAT and virutlaization, and i did everything i could in the system configuration so it will run a windows phone emulator....

Answer (score 0):

System Control -> Programms and Functions -> "Activate or deactivate Windows Features" (in the left bar)

(freely translated from my german win8.1)

There you can activate Hyper-V if it is inside your Windows-version. Then try to restart VS2013 and start the emulator. I had to "deactivate" my Hyper-V and activate it again for some reason. Then it worked.

Good Luck! :)

Comment: Then you might need an Upgrade to Windows 8.1 Professional or Ultimate or Enterprise =/ (I don't remember exactly what versions of Windows 8.1 are out there.. ^^")

Comment: I tried to find out how to do that but i bought my laptop with Windows 8 built in so i dont have Serial Code from the Windows 8 product and i dont have a clue how to upgrade my system to Professional

Comment: @user3375778 you have to buy the upgrade key

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Phone 8 emulator is a special Hyper-V image. It cannot run on other virtualization technology.

Without the emulator, the alternative option would be to use an actual device.

you can use a virtual machine to deploy windows phone 8 OS. Your System processor does not support hyper-v so, you can install win phone 8 on a virtual machine. you would found this link helpful.. check it out: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WANk_XaovqM

Answer (score 0):

Step which i followed; ( I already have windows 8.1 64-bit machine )
Enabled 'Virtualization / Hardware assisted virtualization' in bios. [ https://www.google.co.in/search?q=enable+virtualization+in+bios&oq=enable+virtual&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.5117j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8 ].

Hyper-V option came in 'windows features' after I did this step. 
Later, I Became a member of Hyper-V admin group.